# id cannot be resolved or is not a field again

Tags: eclipse, if-statement, field

Ok this is the code in my single java file:

```
package text.test;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TexttestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button btn;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    EditText piaf=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fieldd);
    piaf.setText("Inception" + "The lord of the Rings");

    }


}
```

I keep getting that error! WTF is wrong?! i tried to google for an answer but nothing worked!

Comment: Can you add the content of the layout/main.xml, so we are able to review android:id value.

Answer (score 0):

should

```
EditText piaf=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fieldd);
```

be

```
EditText piaf=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.field);
```

??

Comment: no...I just changed it from field to fieldd in both files thinking it may work,but the same error...